# Based on a matrix A, generate a matrix B with all possible multiplications of the columns of Matrix A

Tags: matlab, matrix

Say I have a matrix with 3 columns: `c1`, `c2`,`c3`, and I want to create a new matrix in which each column is any possible product of two of the columns of this matrix.

So, if I had a matrix with **d** columns, I would like to create a new matrix with **d+d(d-1)/2+d** columns. For example, consider the matrix with 3 columns `c1`, `c2`,`c3`. The matrix that I would like to create should have the columns `c1`, `c2`,`c3`, `c1xc2`, `c2xc3`,`c1xc3`, `c1^2`, `c2^2` and `c3^2`.

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm embarrassed to post this - I'm sure there must be a simpler way (there is a **MUCH** simpler way - see my december update at the bottom of the answer), but this will do the job:

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
n =  size(A, 2);

B = A(:, reshape(ones(n, 1) * (1:n), 1, n^2)) .* repmat(A, 1, n);
Soln = [A, B(:, logical(reshape(tril(toeplitz(ones(n, 1))), 1, n^2)'))];
```

The calculation is not efficient, since in the `B` step I actually calculate double the number of combinations that I need (ie I get c1.*c1,  c1.*c2,  c1.*c3,  c2.*c1,  c2.*c2,  c2.*c3,  c3.*c1,  c3.*c2,  c3.*c3), and then in the second step I pull out only the columns that I need (eg I get rid of c3.*c1 as I've already got c1.*c3 and so on).

**UPDATE:** Was just out driving and a much better method occurred to me. You just need to construct two index vectors of the form: `I1 = [1 1 1 2 2 3]` and `I2 = [1 2 3 2 3 3]`, then `(A(:, I1) .* A(:, I2))` will get you all the column products you are after. I'm away from my computer at the moment, but will come back later and work out a general way to construct the index vectors. I think it can be fairly easily accompished using the `tril(toeplitz)` construction. Cheers. Will update in a few hours.

**UPDATE:** Rody's second solution (+1) is exactly what I had in mind with my previous update so I won't bother repeating what he has done there now. Yoda's is quite neat too actually, so another +1.

**DECEMBER UPDATE:** Funnily enough, after working on it here, I had to revisit this problem for my own research (coding up White's test for heteroscedasticity). I'm actually favoring a new approach now, recommended (somewhat cryptically) by @slayton in the comments. Specifically, using `nchoosek`. My new solution looks like this:

```
T = 20; K = 4;
X = randi(100, T, K);
Index = nchoosek((1:K), 2);
XAll = [X, X(:, Index(:, 1)) .* X(:, Index(:, 2)), X.^2];
```

`nchoosek` yields exactly the indices we need to construct the cross-products quickly and easily!

Comment: I just completed my answer and only then saw your edit; we're clearly on the same page here :) +1 for you. I didn't know the `toeplitz` and `hankel` commands, those will definitely come in useful in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The following is somewhat decent:

```
B = arrayfun(@(x) circshift(A, [0 -x]), 0:size(A,2)-1, 'UniformOutput', false);
B = cat(2, ones(size(A)), B{:});

C = repmat(A, 1, size(A,2)+1) .* B
```

This will however result in the matrix

```
c1 c2 c3 (c1.*c1) (c2.*c2) (c3.*c3) (c1.*c2) (c2.*c3) (c3.*c1) (c1.*c3) (c2.*c1) (c3.*c2)
```

of which the sequence is different than what you asked, and the products are not unique. If you only want all unique products, use this:

```
[sA1, sA2] = size(A);

aa = repmat(1:sA2, sA2,1);

C = [A, A(:,nonzeros(triu(aa))).*A(:,nonzeros(triu(aa.')))]
```

which results in

```
c1 c2 c3 (c1.*c1) (c2.*c1) (c2.*c2) (c3.*c1) (c3.*c2) (c3.*c3)
```

which is a different sequence than you asked for, but it contains only the unique products.

Does the sequence matter for your purpose?

Comment: Your second solution +1 is exactly what I had in mind, but I wasn't confident enough that I could write it down without testing it in Matlab first :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative. First, define a function that returns all possible pairs (as per your requirements in the question) for a given number of columns:

```
cols=@(n)cat(1,num2cell((1:n)'),num2cell((1:n)'*[1,1],2),num2cell(nchoosek(1:n,2),2))
```

The function should be fairly self-explanatory. Try looking at the output for a few small values of `n` and see for yourself. With this in place, you can proceed as follows:

```
s = RandStream('twister','Seed',1); %for reproducibility 
x = rand(s, 4, 3) %your matrix

%    0.4170    0.1468    0.3968
%    0.7203    0.0923    0.5388
%    0.0001    0.1863    0.4192
%    0.3023    0.3456    0.6852

o = cellfun(@(c)prod(x(:,c),2),cols(size(x,2)),'UniformOutput',0);
out = cat(2,o{:})

%    0.4170    0.1468    0.3968    0.1739    0.0215    0.1574    0.0612    0.1655    0.0582
%    0.7203    0.0923    0.5388    0.5189    0.0085    0.2903    0.0665    0.3881    0.0498
%    0.0001    0.1863    0.4192    0.0000    0.0347    0.1757    0.0000    0.0000    0.0781
%    0.3023    0.3456    0.6852    0.0914    0.1194    0.4695    0.1045    0.2072    0.2368
```